# How to select a nested button inside a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, toggle

I am trying to create a button that toggles a container 
I currently have it working where if a user clicks anywhere on the header the container will toggle, but I want the click function to be working on a button that is nested inside a list which is inside the header.

Currently the code only works by selecting the header. I want it to work only when the user clicks the toggle button. I have tried `$("button").click` `$(".projectHeader > button")` I have also tried selecting using `parent().children()`

can someone help me understand how i can select the toggle button on the click function? I have tried several things and I am pretty stuck, below is the jquery and here is a link to jsfiddle. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/2o0wx8x4/

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {  
            console.log('page has loaded');
          $(".projectHeader").click(function()
          {
            console.log('button was clicked');
            $(this).next('.tableContainer').slideToggle("slow");
             $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
             return false;
            console.log('the table container closed');
          });
        });
    </script>
            <div class="projectWrapper">
                <div class="projectHeader">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <button id="toggleButton">Toggle</button> </li>
                        <li> Project Name </li>
                        <li> Status </li>
                        <li> Budget </li>
                        <li> Client Req Start Date </li>
                        <li> Project Start Date </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Show All</a> </li>
                        <li> can be staffed () </li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
                <div class="tableContainer"> table goes in here</div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('page has loaded');
    j$(".projectHeader button").click(function () {
        console.log('button was clicked');
        j$(this).closest('.projectHeader').next('.tableContainer').slideToggle("slow");
        j$(this).closest('.projectWrapper').siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        return false;
        console.log('the table container closed');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2o0wx8x4/2/)**

Use `$(".projectHeader button")` to select the buttons only. Then, `closest('.projectHeader')` travels up the DOM to the closest `.projectHeader`, and `.next('.tableContainer')` selects the next sibling div to toggle. You then need to select `.closest('.projectWrapper')` in order to close all the sibling containers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input this works great. I am curious to know why do you do .closest('.projectHeader') and also why you select the projectWrapper as well? is "this" in those lines the button?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Hello, do you know how I could make it so that the divs stay open I want the user to close them manually I have been trying to do this for a few days now and i am very stuck! I actually am able to get them to remain open, but i want to use a single button to open/close and for some reason I cant get the buttons to swap on click. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Doesn't the user have to click the toggle button to close it now?

Comment: sorry that wasn't very clear. what I mean is currently, when a user clicks one button it opens the div, but if that user clicks the following button for the div under it the div above it closes. I would like it to remain open so this way the user can view both at the same time. I am trying to make a jsfiddle at the moment with my updated code that might help clarify

Comment: I just realized that your jsfiddle you sent me works the way i want it...for some reason when i add it to my page it works differently...hmm I am working in salesforce

Comment: I fixed it! for some reason the '.siblings.children()' doesnt seem to work properly so instead i did '.siblings('.tableContainer').next()'

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't load the fiddle (secured network), but here's how you can add a click handler on the button and get a reference to it's closest `.projectHeader`.

```
$('.projectHeader button').click(function () {
    var header = $(this).closest('.projectHeader');
    //from here you should be good to go
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to other answers, but also collpases all other expended entries.

http://jsfiddle.net/2o0wx8x4/3/

As per your formatting:

```
j$(document).ready(function()
        {  
            console.log('page has loaded');
          j$(".projectHeader button.toggleButton").click(function()
          {
             //get the parent div
             var parent = j$(this).parent().parent().parent();
             console.log('button was clicked');
             parent.addClass("clicked");

             parent.next('.tableContainer').slideToggle("slow");
             j$(".projectHeader:not(.clicked)").next().slideUp();
             parent.removeClass("clicked");
             parent.parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
             return false;
          });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this works great in the jsfiddle but for some reason the last two buttons dont seem to work on my project :( would you mind explaining why you write parent() three times? what does this mean which parent are you grabbing?